# How to unmount and shrink system's partition size?

Tags: partitioning

I've a system partition of 740GB which is way more than needed, I just need less than 64GB but I don't know how to unmount the system's partition since Ubuntu always needs it.

```
Number Start  End    Size   File system    Name                 Flags
1      1049kB 256GB  256GB  ntfs           Basic data partition msftdata
2      256GB  256GB  256MB  fat32                               boot, esp
3      256GB  260GB  4096MB linux-swap(v1) 
4      260GB  1000GB 740GB  ext4
```

I just want to shrink the system's partition (the ext4 one) to add another data partition, because, Ubuntu won't need a lot of space, 64GB is enougth for me.

Comment: Would be best to boot from a live USB(same one you installed with).  16GB would be a bit small, I would not go much below 50GB(for future use).  25GB should be minimum so you have space for updates.  Gparted on live USB/DVD will shrink partition to size you want.

Comment: System partitions can't be manipulated unless you booted from a different device. crip659's right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/)

Comment: @Léolol DB You must boof from a LiveUSB to resize both your Linux and Windows partitions. DO YOU USE HIBERNATION? Then you MUST have a swap partition = your RAM size. DO YOU USE UBUNTU 17.10 OR HIGHER? If yes, then you can use a Swap File, which is now just as fast and far more flexible, and eliminate /dev/sda2 . IF you do NOT use Hibernation AND you use Ubuntu 17.10 or higher, I wd suggest you delete /dev/sda3 and make a swap file instead, so you can use the space of /dev/sda3 elsewhere. Ubuntu and read and write your NTFS partition (C:) safely. See http://gparted.org for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when I tried to resize with the Live Key, it crashed and the system's partition got corrupted, in fact the Live Key I used ran into issues so I needed another key, if you got the same issue, here is how I did:

- I formatted another working key with a .iso file of Ubuntu (I had on
  another computer)
- Then I re-installed Ubuntu
  (and resized the partitions in the same time), yay!

*Really I'm really surprised and it works better than before, I'm not mad at all.*